# SDN: How the controller can get the installed flows on switch?

Tags: sdn, opendaylight, openflow, pox

According to described here
http://flowgrammable.org/sdn/openflow/message-layer/flowmod/
and in the OpenFlow switch specifications, the flow_mod message is not acknowledgeable.

Is there any way for the controller (POX, ODL, or any other) to receive a confirmation for installed flow match or to retrieve the installed flows in the switch's flow table?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There is a concept in openflow called "barrier" where the controller
can send a barrier request to have the switch acknowledge the flow_mod.

In OpenDaylight, the default openflowplugin stats collection will poll
the connected switches and will store the config (including the flow table)
in OpenDaylight's operational store.